# Testing extra actions with overridden view attributes

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet with an [extra action](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) that needs to behave differently than the rest of the viewset with respect to authentication and authorization.

E.g.

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [SomeClass]
    permission_classes = [AnotherClass]
    queryset = Model.objects.some_important_ones()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    @list_route(methods=['post', 'options'], authentication_classes=[])
    def action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = so_something_specific(request)
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The testing set up is

```
@pytest.fixture
def request():
    return APIRequestFactory()


def test_the_data_was_created(request):
    req = request.post('/api/my-model/action/', payload={}, format='json')
    view = MyModelViewSet.as_view({'post': 'action'})
    res = view(req)
    assert res.status_code == 201
```

So the issue is that the response always complains about authentication not being provided but the action doesn't actually need it!
The repr looks like this:

```
<Response status_code=401, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Content

```
'{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}'
```

Question is, how might I go about getting the callable to operate as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being really simple. Looking at the router [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L281), I just needed to pass in the initialization keyword arguments to match what the `@list_route` decorator was doing like so:

```
view = MyModelViewSet.as_view({'post': 'action'}, **{'authentication_classes': []})
```